# javascript scope issue causing infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to make and ajax call 30 times but this is resulting in an infinite loop. It is certainly a scope issue relating to the data array but cant seem to track it down.

```
var data = [], totalPoints = 30;
function getData() {
    var value = 0.0;
    if (data.length > 0)
        data = data.slice(1);

    url = "some/url"

    while (data.length < totalPoints) {
        $.getJSON(url, {metric_name : "someMetric"})
         .done(function(json ) {
            value = json;
            console.log(value);
            data.push(value.metricValue);
         });
    }
}
```

Comment: AJAX is *asynchronous*!  Your `data` array isn't updated until the AJAX call is done.

Comment: AJAX isn't **always** asynchronous. @OP -- you're doing a `while` loop on an array until the array length is less than 30. However, each loop of `while` seems to be adding one element to the array. Therefore, the while loop will never complete if it meets the conditions required to start.

Comment: @Chris: It is unless you explicitly tell it not to be.

Comment: @RocketHazmat -- ... indeed, making it not always asynchronous. That's like saying "a loop is infinite. (unless you make it end)". Which means that loops are not infinite. Just sayin'

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a very specific case for the questioner, unlikely to have any value for future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$.getJSON` call is async so you can't follow a procedural scheme; you can set it up the call as sync by using a low level `$.ajax` and using the async option as `false`.

> async (default: true) Type: Boolean By default, all requests are sent
>   asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need
>   synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests
>   and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.
>   Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser,
>   disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8,
>   the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you
>   must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the
>   corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the
>   deprecated jqXHR.success().

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Code (not tested..):

```
var data = [],
    totalPoints = 30;

function getData() {
    var value = 0.0;
    if (data.length > 0) data = data.slice(1);

    url = "some/url"

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            value = json;
            console.log(value);
            data.push(value.metricValue);
        },
        data: {
            metric_name: "someMetric"
        },
        async: false
    });
}
```

Comment: I ***highly*** suggest ***NOT*** using `async: false`.  This **will** lock up (freeze) the browser until the AJAX call is done.

Comment: I totally agree with you; but without reconsider the whole code is the only current solution that I can see